# Can I change the outcome of completed story missions?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-2

According to my career record, I've done an unsatisfactory job of searching Menendez's compound. Does this have significant consequences and can I change the outcome by replaying the mission?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No...you can hit rewind story. It's <kbd>R1</kbd> on PlayStation so I'm assuming it's <kbd>RB</kbd> on Xbox. I don't know about PC. It gives you the option to rewind story so that the events and outcomes are different. If you hit replay mission and select a mission, you can rewind the story back to there.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you cannot. I've spent almost an hour trying to redo that same level a few times just to find out that if you want to change the outcome you have to redo the ENTIRE campaign, I think I read it on Gamefront. It's extremely irritating. Hope this helps.

Comment: I see, thanks for the answer and welcome to the site! Do you know if these outcomes have a significant effect on the game?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redo a mission, then you'll have to redo everything from that mission onward. So for example, if you wanted to change the outcome of Suffer With Me, you'd then play the four missions that follow it.

Comment: Bryce, are you sure about that? I just dont want to waste an hour or two redoing missions and then finding out you were wrong... I just want ot make sure you are 100% correct.